# Run Test in Test Cafe Studio nightly

Tags: javascript, testing, continuous-integration, testcafe, end-to-end

I have a test created in Test Cafe Studios.  I would like to have that test run automatically each night without needing a user to run the test (open the program, click start, etc) Is such a thing possible with this software?  It would be helpful if there were some example of how to solve this! I have pasted some of the code for a very basic test, just checking if the pages will open. I have filled-in some of the '' with generic information for the question

Thanks in advance.

Windows Task Scheduler

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `svdemo`
.page `my website here `
.httpAuth({
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    domain: 'domain'
});

test('Visit Each Page', async t => {
await t
    .click(Selector('span').withText('Page1'))
    .click(Selector('a').withText('Homepage'))
    .click(Selector('a').withText('Page2'))
    .click(Selector('a').withText('Homepage'))
    .click(Selector('a').withText('Page3'));
```

});

I expect to see the test run and pass each night on its own.

Answer (score 10):

You need to use any Continuous Integration system for this purpose. The CI system supports automatic test execution instead of running tests manually using the UI. Take a look at the topic about how to use TestCafe with modern [Continuous Integration](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/continuous-integration/) systems.
 
As another way, you can try to use Windows Task Scheduler as it is described here [What is the best way to run Node script continuously on Windows (for example, automatically run it daily)?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-run-Node-script-continuously-on-Windows-for-example-automatically-run-it-daily)